# Get Details Entity By Id in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, textbox

I'm having a problem. I do not know how can display product information by entering the product code into the textbox then I press the tab button or move the mouse off the textbox it will automatically display detailed information on the product below. Like the TextChanged event in WebForm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

having the html

```
<input type='text' id='mytxt' />
<div id='details'> </div>
```

you would do:

```
$('#mytxt').change(function(){
    $.post('<%:Url.Action("Details")%>', { id: $(this).val()}, function(result){
       $('#details').html(result);
    }
});
```

and the action in mvc would look like this:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
   //get the content somehow
   ...
   return Content(thecontent);    
}
```

Comment: I' a newbie in asp.net mvc, but I'm urgently in this regard. you can make a more specific example not thank you. I did then, but it still does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's focusout() method to make an ajax call that will return a partial view when the textbox loses focus (i.e. tab is pressed or another input element is focused).